# How JSF 2.3 websocket work with Ajax with f:ajax actionlisenter?

Tags: jsf, websocket, ajax-update

I have tried to taste the new features of JSF 2.3, one attractive is the websocket.

I have read some sample codes from mojarra tests and JSF 2.3 specific `@Push` javadoc.

And encountered some issues when used `f:websocket` and `f:ajax`.

The facelets template is:

```
   <h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
        <ul>
            <ui:repeat value="#{ajaxBean.messages}" var="m">
                <li>#{m}</li>
            </ui:repeat>
        </ul>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:form id="form">
        <h:commandButton 
            id="sendMessage" 
            action="#{ajaxBean.sendMessage()}" 
            value="Send Ajax Message">
            <f:ajax/>
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
    <h:form>
        <f:websocket channel="ajaxChannel" scope="view">
            <f:ajax event="ajaxEvent" render=":messagePanel" />
        </f:websocket>
    </h:form>
    <h:form>
        <f:websocket channel="ajaxListenerChannel" scope="view">
            <f:ajax event="ajaxListenerEvent" listener="#{ajaxBean.ajaxPushed}" render=":messagePanel" />
        </f:websocket>
    </h:form>

    <f:websocket channel="commandScriptChannel" scope="view" onmessage="onCommandScript"/>
    <h:form>
        <h:commandScript name="onCommandScript" action="#{ajaxBean.commandScriptExecuted()}" render=":messagePanel"/>
    </h:form>
```

And backend bean is:

```
@ViewScoped
@Named("ajaxBean")
public class AjaxBean implements Serializable {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(AjaxBean.class.getName());

    @Inject
    @Push
    PushContext ajaxChannel;

    @Inject
    @Push
    PushContext ajaxListenerChannel;

    @Inject
    @Push
    PushContext commandScriptChannel;

    private List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();

    public void ajaxPushed(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) throws AbortProcessingException{
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "ajax pushed: " + e.toString());

        messages.add("ajaxListenerEvent is sent at: " + LocalDateTime.now());

        ajaxListenerChannel.send("ajaxListenerEvent");
    }

    public void commandScriptExecuted() {
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "commandScriptExecuted pushed.");

        messages.add("commandScriptExecuted message is sent at: " + LocalDateTime.now());

        commandScriptChannel.send("onCommandScript");
    }

    public void sendMessage() {
//        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "ajax pushed by button: " + e.toString());

        messages.add("ajaxEvent is sent at: " + LocalDateTime.now());

        ajaxChannel.send("ajaxEvent");
    }

    public List<String> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    public void setMessages(List<String> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }

}
```

The result is the first button can trigger the ajax output as needed. But f:ajax with a listener does not work, and h:commandScript also does not work here.

How to correct these?

Comment: But you're nowhere in your code explicitly pushing to those channels? Moreover, those channels are only pushed by their own ajax/command listener! I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @BalusC I added **push** action in the f:ajax `listener` and h:commandScript `action`. The `@Push` javadoc explains use f:websocket with f:ajax to handle complex UI. What I want to use f:webocket and f:ajax or h:commandScript is to execute the backend action and append content automatically. Can I archive this purpose? or I misunderstand the f:webscoket/f:ajax usage.

Comment: @BalusC I have updated the [codes](https://github.com/hantsy/ee8-sandbox/tree/master/jsf-websocket), if use an extra button to push the ajax signal to channel, it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your concrete problem is caused because you're nowhere in your code explicitly sending a push message to those websockets. If your attempt were possible in some way, the websocket would keep sending a push message to itself in an infinite loop. This doesn't make sense.

In order to explicitly send a push message, you have to let your code explicitly call `push.send(message)`, exactly as you already did with that `<h:commandButton>`.

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Send push message" action="#{bean.sendPushMessage}">
        <f:ajax />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
<h:form>
    <f:websocket channel="pushWithAjaxUpdate" scope="view">
        <f:ajax event="updateMessages" listener="#{bean.updateMessages}" render=":messages" />
    </f:websocket>
</h:form>
<h:panelGroup id="messages" layout="block">
    <ul>
        <ui:repeat value="#{bean.messages}" var="message">
            <li>#{message}</li>
        </ui:repeat>
    </ul>
</h:panelGroup>
```

```
@Inject @Push
private PushContext pushWithAjaxUpdate;

public void sendPushMessage() {
    messages.add("Push message is sent at: " + LocalDateTime.now());
    pushWithAjaxUpdate.send("updateMessages");
}

public void updateMessages() {
    messages.add("Ajax event is received at: " + LocalDateTime.now());
}
```

I understand that you're just experimenting, but it should be said that above approach wouldn't make sense in real world code either. The `<f:websocket>` is superfluous in this specific use case and it would suffice to just use `<h:commandButton><f:ajax listener="...">`. It's in real world code expected that the push is not synchronously invoked by some command button in the very same page, but that it is **asynchronously** invoked by some business event. Otherwise you could as good just return the result in the ajax response itself. This saves an additional round-trip to the server.

Comment: I'm trying the very same example and I cant reRender messages component.
The only way to make it work was, `<f:websocket channel="otherChannel" scope="application" onmessage="onMessage"/>` and a JS script writing html basic logic

Comment: In my case was wrong dependency 
 `<dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-jsf</artifactId>
                <version>15.0.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>`

Comment: How can i do it **without commandButton**? I sent a push message using observer method invoked by observable bean. But nothing pushed.